# Way to get assign the Object in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

I have Object obj in jquery

```
var obj = {};
```

I have the string `str`

```
var str = "passengerDetails[0].photo";
```

Now I am assigning this `str` as key in Object `obj` like below

```
obj = {str : "xx"} //means {"passengerDetails[0].photo" : xx} should come
```

But it is assigning as `obj ={"str":"xx"};`
What is the simple solution to this jquery Object code?

Comment: Do you want something like `{"passengerDetails":[{"photo":"xx"}]}`?

Answer (score 2):

Try ,

```
var obj = {};

var str = "passengerDetails[0].photo";

obj[str] = "xx"; //it should work

console.log(obj); //Outputs -->  Object { passengerDetails[0].photo="xx"}
```

Answer (score 0):

var obj = {};

var str = "passengerDetails[0].photo";

obj[str] = "xx"; //it should work

console.log(obj); //Outputs -->  Object { passengerDetails[0].photo="xx"}

//Thanks a lot to CodingAnt and this answer working like a boss